# tsc is not recognized as inter. or ext. command

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, npm

I am trying to set-up my TypeScript in my computer but I simply cannot get it to work. I have tried everything I found but nothing worked for me.

Here is what I did:

1) Downloaded `TypeScript for VS2015` from microsoft website and installed it. This has created two folders (maybe more than these, but these are the ones I could trace)

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.7
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.8

2) Then started my VS2015 with my ASP.NET 5 project and tried running following command under VS Command Prompt (from within the app)

`tsc --version`

I got the error message (subject of this question).

3) After that I tried another solution and ran `npm install -g typescript` from VS Command prompt (from within my app). Afterwards I was still getting the same error message.

4) I went to my system variables and added the following: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.8\` to my `Path` variables. The error message still there.

I have basically used all the ideas from the Internet and still cannot get it to work. Any help in this matter would be highly appreciated.

P.S. After each step I restarted my `explorer.exe` in order for system to re-load all variables

P.S.2: Under my app, I have also added file `tsconfig.json` with the following code:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, good old shut down & restart solved the problem.